# Shortcut keys to comment on HTML code in Atom

Tags: html, comments, atom-editor, shortcut

I want to use shortcut keys to comment on some HTML codes in Atom. But when I use 'ctrl'+'/', I got {# html_code_block #} instead of <!-- html_code_block ->. 
What are the shortcut keys to comment on HTML code in Atom or how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

'ctrl'+'/' should work , what version are you using ? (I checked in v 1.6)

Comment: My Atom is 1.60.0 too. Is it because I have some packages installed?

Comment: can you check your keybindings settings ? just open settings->Keybindings

Comment: Just tried with a fresh installation, 'ctrl'+'/' works. It looks like an installed package caused the issue. I will find it out.

Comment: can you share the package name here?

Comment: When I disable a package called "django-templates", 'ctrl'+'/' works. But I really need this package. I tried to change the combination of shortcut keys, but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: map your django-templates's `ctrl-/` keybinding to a different keybinding. You can do it in your keymap file (keymap.cson file). Open `Packages-> Keybindings Resolver -> Toggle` to see the current keybinding for `ctrl-/`

Comment: The current keybinding is ctrl-/ (editor:toggle-line-comments). I also tried to add new shortcut keys (for example shift-c) in keymap.cson. They didn't work.

Comment: I changed 'commentStart' and 'commentEnd' keys in file   .atom\packages\django-templates\settings\django-templates.CSON. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is caused by an installed package called "django-templates". The solution is to change 'commentStart' value to <!-- and 'commentEnd' value to --> in file .atom\packages\django-templates\settings\django-templates.CSON.